# How can I get means in each column?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a big data frame like this:

```
ID  c_Al   c_D    c_Hy      occ
A     0     0      0        2306
B     0     0      0        3031
C     0     0      1        2581
D     0     0      1        1917
E     0     0      1        2708
F     0     1      0        2751
G     0     1      0        1522
H     0     1      0        657
I     0     1      1        469
J     0     1      1        2629
L     1     0      0        793
L     1     0      0        793
M     1     0      0        564
N     1     0      1        2617
O     1     0      1        1167
P     1     0      1        389
Q     1     0      1        294
R     1     1      0        1686
S     1     1      0        992
```

How can I get means in each column?

```
               0        1
    c_Al    1506.2  1641.2
    c_D     748.6   1467.5
    c_Hy    1506.2  1641.2
```

I have tried `aggregate(occ~c_Al, mean, data=table2)`, but it has to be done many times; `ddply` has the same results, or `for(i in 1:dim(table2)[1]){ aggregate(occ~[,i], mean, data=table2)}`, but it can't work.

Comment: Maybe something simpler, like `colMeans`?

Comment: Are your results just an example of the format you want or the actual results you expect to get?

Comment: @AnandaMahto it just an example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would just use `melt` and `dcast` from "reshape2":

```
library(reshape2)
dfL <- melt(table2, id.vars = c("ID", "occ"))
dcast(dfL, variable ~ value, value.var = "occ", fun.aggregate = mean)
#   variable        0        1
# 1     c_Al 2057.100 1032.778
# 2      c_D 1596.667 1529.429
# 3     c_Hy 1509.500 1641.222
```

---

Of course, base R can handle this just fine too.

Here, I've used `tapply` and `vapply`:

```
vapply(table2[2:4], function(x) tapply(table2$occ, x, mean), numeric(2L))
#       c_Al      c_D     c_Hy
# 0 2057.100 1596.667 1509.500
# 1 1032.778 1529.429 1641.222
t(vapply(table2[2:4], function(x) tapply(table2$occ, x, mean), numeric(2L)))
#             0        1
# c_Al 2057.100 1032.778
# c_D  1596.667 1529.429
# c_Hy 1509.500 1641.222
```

Comment: *love* this use of `vapply`!

Comment: @AndrewMacDonald, Thanks! `sapply` does it just fine, but is usually slower because of `simplify2array`, so these days, when I get the chance, I prefer `vapply`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr`. If `dat` is the dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) 

dat%>% 
gather(Var,Value, c_Al:c_Hy)%>%
group_by(Value,Var)%>% 
summarize(occ=mean(occ))%>% 
spread(Value, occ)
 Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

#   Var        0        1
# 1 c_Al 2057.100 1032.778
# 2  c_D 1596.667 1529.429
# 3 c_Hy 1509.500 1641.222
```

Comment: Better than mine -- double-grouping is the way to go here; certainly much easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this via `dplyr` and `tidyr`.  Similar to @akrun's approach, but keeping the data in a "wider" format (for no particular reason)

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

new_df <- df %>% 
  gather(category,value,c_Al:c_Hy) %>%
  mutate(ids = 1:n()) %>%
  #unique %>%
  spread(value,occ,fill = NA)

mean_na <- function(x) mean(x,na.rm = TRUE)

new_df %>% 
  group_by(category) %>%
  select(-ID,-ids) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean_na))

  category        0        1
1     c_Al 2057.100 1032.778
2      c_D 1596.667 1529.429
3     c_Hy 1509.500 1641.222
```

Comment: I don't think these results are correct. Try a manual calculation and see.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Quite right! It turns out that one must be careful what one defines as "fill" values ;P

Comment: Better now. +1. (But you need to edit your first sentence now).

Answer (score 1):

alternative in plain R:

```
sapply(0:1, 
       function(i) sapply(colnames(df[2:4]), 
                          function(column) mean(df[df[,column]==i, "occ"])))
```

EDIT: or, as requested with colnames in the result (replaced 0:1 by a vector with named elements):

```
sapply(c("0"=0, "1"=1), 
       function(i) sapply(colnames(df[2:4]), 
                          function(column) mean(df[df[,column]==i, "occ"])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using only `colSums` and subsetting by considering the matrix stucture of the problem:

```
cbind(`0`=colSums((x[,2:4]-1)*x[,5]*-1)/colSums(x[,2:4]==0),
      `1`=colSums(x[,2:4]*x[,5])/colSums(x[,2:4]==1))
            0        1
c_Al 2057.100 1032.778
c_D  1596.667 1529.429
c_Hy 1509.500 1641.222
```